# Same redirect uri for multiple providers in oidc

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I want to have my relying party app (RP) be able to connect with any oidc provider.
That means that users will be able to set up any identity provider that supports openid connect.

Therefor I want my RP app to have a single redirect uri, for example

> http://www.example.com/auth/callback

So that all IDPs will call the same one in auth code flow.

How would the RP distinguish between each IDP ? and know which IDP to call to complete the oauth flow ?

Comment: Can I ask how the app knows which provider to use? Seems chicken and egg. User specifies provider but user not authenticated. Trying something similar myself and going round in circles. Hoping for all users to be able to access via the same URL but all I can think is separate URLs per user... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [state](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) parameter of the auth request:

> `state` Opaque value used to maintain state between the request and the callback ...

The state value would contain both a random part and an auth privider identifier. For example "google-A41DsGDm". The auth provider is supposed to return the same state value with the redirect URL containing an auth code. So your `/auth/callback` handler would know, which auth provider's `/token` endpoint to call to get tokens (after validation of the random part of the state value).

For completeness, if you just wanted to use a single backend handler, you could map all URIs starting with `/auth/callback` to the handler and accept the following path param as auth provider identifier. For example `/auth/callback/google?code=...`.

Comment: you should be aware of the recommendation that one may use *different* redirect URIs to mitigate IDP mixup attacks: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-lodderstedt-oauth-security-topics-00#section-2.6

Comment: Who decides on the idp name ? If I have a predefined list, then it's not really generic approach for any idp. If the user decided on the name of the idp then i'll have to associate the name with specific idp somehow. One user might write `google` and another one as `goog` but I need to know they both mean Google.

Maybe I need to generate a random identifier for the idp and map it to a specific idp. For example `ukjsd3hb` will be mapped to Google and I will query the db to look up the mapping and have `/auth/callback/ukjsd3hb?code=...` as the handler

Comment: I meant to say that when the user first sets up the auth server in my app, they are given a random identifier that they will have to input in their auth server settings. I will know the mapping (db lookup)

Comment: The way you generate the identifier and prevent duplicates is up to you. It doesn't need to be human readable. But if you generate it in your application, the user will have to generate the identifier first and then set up the client's redirect URIs at the auth provider.